# Native AlertView buttons are not showing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

[image]

I am using normal `UIAlertView`. showing fine in ios 6 but in ios 7 button titles are not displaying.

```
UIAlertView *theAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                   message:@"This is the message."
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
[theAlert show];
```

I have an issue. I have Category for `TableViewCell`

```
@implementation UITableViewCell(IOS7FIX)

- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake( 1, 0, 60,50);
}

@end
```

This is creating the issue.

Comment: Tried `OtherButtonTitles` too ? XCode version ?

Comment: Did you mess up with tint colors? I.e. is it there but "grey on grey"?

Comment: Do you have any category related to UIAlertView ? Also, what is XCode version ?

Comment: nop. i didn't overrided any where in project or dont have nay categories.

Comment: Can you replicate this in a completely new project documenting everything you did between starting the project and encountering the problem? This is not the default behavior, and it doesn't just happen on its own.  Something you've done caused this.

Comment: No. i have completed over all project in xcode 4.5 , now upgraded to xcode 5.

Comment: I am using XCode 5.0.2, it is working fine, what is your's version ?

Comment: on other application i have created working fine.

Comment: @Nookaraju in my code alert button text showing perfectly .

Comment: @Nookaraju this code try in other page . and check it .

Comment: check if you have somewhere in your code... contentInset for tableview , se;f.view, etc... ; try to comment that line :)

Comment: no bro. if i remove implementation UITableViewCell(IOS7FIX)
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake( 1, 0, 60,50);
}
 then showing fine. but we cannot write category for UITableViewCell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
```

belongs to UIView and this implementation might impact all UIViews since its a generic implementation. So I would suggest you to better **sub-class** your `UITableViewCell` and put a check like this in sub-class, this is the dynamic compilation and will run this code for iOS7 or later version(s).

```
- (void) layoutSubviews 
{
     // Do your stuff here

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 70000
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake( 1, 0, 60,50);
#endif

     // Do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. sub-classing worked. Learnt new lession :)